# Values not being placed in array

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Im creating a revision timetable for a school project that lets the user choose subjects and how many hours they want for each one, before inputting them into a 2d-array the user can use as a table. I have written the following code that takes the array $subject through post of a previous page.

$subject is a 2d-array with the first level being the subjects the user choose and the second being how many hours the user wants for that subject.

The code should take the $subject array and use it in a number of functions to populate the array but when I run the code I just get an empty array

Here is the code

```
<?php
$timetable = array(

"0" => array      // 0 = Monday 6 = Sunday
    // 0 - 23 = horus
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"1" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"2" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"3" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"4" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"5" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
),
"6" => array
(
    "0" => '',
    "1" => '',
    "2" => '',
    "3" => '',
    "4" => '',
    "5" => '',
    "6" => '',
    "7" => '',
    "8" => '',
    "9" => '',
    "10" => '',
    "11" => '',
    "12" => '',
    "13" => '',
    "14" => '',
    "15" => '',
    "16" => '',
    "17" => '',
    "18" => '',
    "19" => '',
    "20" => '',
    "21" => '',
    "22" => '',
    "23" => ''
)
);

$subjects = $_POST;

function pick_random_subject($subjects, $timetable)
{
$available = FALSE;
while ($available == FALSE) {
    $subject = array_rand($subjects);
    if (check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable, $subject)) {
        $available = TRUE;
    }
}
return $subject;
}

function check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable,$subject)
{
$count = 0;
foreach ($timetable as $day) {
    $count += array_count_values($day)[$subject];
}

if ($count < $subjects[$subject]) {
    return True;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function verify_available_slot($timetable, $day, $slot)
{
if ($timetable[$day][$slot] == '') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function pick_random_slot($timetable)
{

$available = FALSE;
while ($available == FALSE) {
    $day = rand(0, 6);
    $hour = rand(0, 23);

    $available = verify_available_slot($timetable, $day, $hour);
}
return [$day, $hour];
}

function Check_end($subjects, $timetable)
{
$finished = FALSE;
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    if (!check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable, $subject)) {
        $finished = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
return $finished;
}
if(isset($_POST)) {
while(Check_end($subjects, $timetable )== FALSE)
{

$subject = pick_random_subject($subjects, $timetable);
$slot = pick_random_slot($subject);
$day = $slot[0];
$hour = $slot[1];
$timetable[$day][$hour] = $subject;
}
}
else {
header('http://localhost/timetable/TimetableAlgorithmn.php');
}

?>
<pre>
<?print_r($timetable) ?>
<pre>
```

Note: I think that the problem lies within the function "check_subject_availability" but im not sure.

Comment: Just a tip: `return $count < $subjects[$subject];` is the same as `if ($count < $subjects[$subject]) {  return True; } else { return false; }` but better readable and probably faster.

Comment: Maybe you could use a for or two to create this huge structure? The code you have is enormous!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it without the surrounding code but at least one problem should lie between the `Check_end()` and `check_subject_availability` calls:

```
function Check_end($subjects, $timetable)
{
$finished = FALSE;
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    if (!check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable, $subject)) {
        $finished = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
return $finished;
}
```

This code assumes the name of the subject is a value e.g. `$subjects == ['subject1']`

While in `check_subject_availability()` you use it as key into subjects e.g. `$subjects == ['subject1' => 5]`

```
function check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable,$subject)
{
$count = 0;
foreach ($timetable as $day) {
    $count += array_count_values($day)[$subject];
}

return $count < $subjects[$subject]; // usage as key
}
```

Maybe changing `foreach ($subjects as $subject)` to `foreach ($subjects as $subject => $max_count)` fixes your problem.

Another bug:

```
while(Check_end($subjects, $timetable )== FALSE)
{
    $subject = pick_random_subject($subjects, $timetable);
    list($day, $hour) = pick_random_slot($timetable);  // $timetable not $subject
    $timetable[$day][$hour] = $subject;
}
```

And finally the last bug (at least to get it working for me:)

```
function Check_end($subjects, $timetable)
{
$finished = TRUE;
foreach ($subjects as $subject => $max_n) {
    if (check_subject_availability($subjects, $timetable, $subject)) {
        $finished = false;
    }
}
return $finished;
}
```

Your version stopped as soon as one subject was !check_subject_availability(). This version stops only if all subjects are not available.

One last tip: You should consider the shuffle approach I use in the code below because your version slowly gets problems when the timetable fills up and you can't find empty slots anymore.

A little add:

```
$timetable = array_fill(0, 7, array_fill(0, 24, ''));
```

constructs exactly the same array as your long array() statement.

A bigger add:
Your code could be refactored to this:

```
$timetable = [];
foreach ($_POST as $subject => $n)  // add in the required amount of subjects
    $timetable = array_merge($timetable, array_fill(0, $n, $subject));
$timetable = array_merge($timetable, array_fill(0, 24 * 7 - count($timetable), ''));  // fill the array with empty values
shuffle($timetable);  // shuffle the set
$timetable = array_chunk($timetable, 24);  // split it into 7 days
```

Comment: Thank you @Christoph  . This almost fixed the issue completely. The array now gets populated but not always the correct amount. So for example If you use 2 subjects Maths(9) and physics(6). The array will populate the first one correctly, ie 9 instances of maths , but a seemingly random amount of the second subject ie only 1 physics.

Comment: @Adam Anderson I've added 6 lines of code that are equivalent to your current code/what you're trying to achieve but if you want me to further search for your bug just let me know.

Comment: @Adam Anderson My answer now contains enough bugs to make your code work. Feel free to accept it or ask further questions :)

Comment: Thank you very much the code you posted works perfectly. I had to change `array_shuffle()` to `shuffle()`

Comment: @AdamAnderson Sure ... `shuffle` of course. Long time no php for me ;) I hope you understood the approach to use `shuffle` instead of `rand`